# How to reference a composite primary key in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, constraints, composite-primary-key

I have created the following 3 tables using the following code.

```
CREATE TABLE BUILDING(
BUILDINGNO CHAR(2),
BUILDINGWING VARCHAR2(15),
BUILDINGLANE VARCHAR2(15),
CONSTRAINT BUILDING_PK PRIMARY KEY(BUILDINGNO));

CREATE TABLE ROOM(
BUILDINGNO CHAR(2),
ROOMNO CHAR(2),
ROOMCAPACITY NUMBER(3),
CONSTRAINT ROOM_PK PRIMARY KEY(BUILDINGNO,ROOMNO),
CONSTRAINT ROOM_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(BUILDINGNO) REFERENCES BUILDING(BUILDINGNO));

CREATE TABLE SPEAKER(
SPEAKERID CHAR(2),
SPEAKERNAME VARCHAR2(20),
SPEAKERADDRESS VARCHAR2(50),
SPEAKERPHONE CHAR(12),
CONSTRAINT SPEAKER_PK PRIMARY KEY(SPEAKERID));
```

The 4th table i need to create is something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE CONFERENCESESSION(
SESSIONID CHAR(4),
BUILDINGNO CHAR(2),
ROOMNO CHAR(2),
SPEAKERID CHAR(2),
SESSIONDATE DATE,
SESSIONPRICE NUMBER(4,2),
CONSTRAINT SESSION_PK PRIMARY KEY(SESSIONID),
CONSTRAINT SESSION_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(BUILDINGNO) REFERENCES BUILDING(BUILDINGNO),
CONSTRAINT SESSION_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(ROOMNO) REFERENCES ROOM(ROOMNO),
CONSTRAINT SESSION_FK3 FOREIGN KEY(SPEAKERID) REFERENCES SPEAKER(SPEAKERID));
```

However I know that the constraint for the FK2 ROOMNO (2nd last line) is incorrect as the PK in the ROOM table is BUILDINGNO,ROOMNO.
What would be the correct code to use for this line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL. How to reference a composite primary key Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204845/sql-how-to-reference-a-composite-primary-key-oracle)

Comment: For future refrence: Please read & act on [mcve]. Also [ask] and [help], and google 'stackexchange homework'. And your error message sans your table names. And the official documentation re FKs. This is a faq. (Could this possibly the first question about this? No.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We declare an SQL FK (FOREIGN KEY) constraint to say that a subrow value for a list of columns always appears elsewhere as a subrow value for a list of columns that forms an SQL PK (PRIMARY KEY) or UNIQUE NOT NULL. Declare it whenever it isn't already implied by other declarations. It must reference the column list in a declared SQL PK (PRIMARY KEY) or UNIQUE NOT NULL. So you must declare that in the referenced table, even if that's already implied by NOT NULLs and a smaller contained PK or UNIQUE NOT NULL.

So note that an SQL PK is not necessarily a PK in the relational sense of being unique but not containing a smaller unique column set, ie being a superkey not containing a smaller superkey, ie being a minimal/irreducible superkey, ie being a CK (candidate key).

Here, you might need to replace the `buildingno` & `roomno` FKs by one, `(buildingno, roomno)` to `Room`:

```
CONSTRAINT SESSION_FK12
    FOREIGN KEY(BUILDINGNO,ROOMNO) REFERENCES ROOM(BUILDINGNO,ROOMNO)
```

That *might* be appropriate for the meanings of your tables--which in fact you don't give, so we can't know, we can only guess. Eg if `buildingno` could *also* be declared PK or UNIQUE NOT NULL in Room, which when `roomno IS NOT NULL` is actually consistent with and implies `(buildingno, roomno)` could be declared PK or UNIQUE NOT NULL, maybe your FK is *right* but your `Room` declarations are inadequate.

When a subrow value for a list of columns always appears elsewhere as a subrow value for a list of columns that is called an IND (inclusion dependency) constraint. There's no way to declare a non-FK IND in SQL; we must enforce by triggers. That *also* might be what you need for your design.

You could keep the FK from `buildingno` to `Building`, but it's implied by the FK I suggest and the FK in `buildingno` on `Room` referencing `Building`.

[referencing part of the composite primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23995608/3404097)

Comment: Would it be correct if I wrote it as: CONSTRAINT SESSION_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(ROOMNO) REFERENCES ROOM(ROOMNO,BUILDINGNO),

Comment: No, because how can a one-column subrow value appear as a two-column subrow value somewhere else? (I'll edit my answer.)

Comment: If I have CONSTRAINT SESSION_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(BUILDINGNO,ROOMNO) REFERENCES ROOM(BUILDINGNO,ROOMNO) then I can remove CONSTRAINT SESSION_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(BUILDINGNO) REFERENCES BUILDING(BUILDINGNO), is that right?

Comment: Yes, my edited question already says that in the last paragraph. (Assuming the PKs & FKs are correct.) And that's why the first sentence says to declare 'when that isn't already implied by other declarations'.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see in [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#i1015710) we can create composite foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE CONFERENCESESSION ...
...
CONSTRAINT SESSION_FK2 
    FOREIGN KEY(BUILDINGNO, ROOMNO) 
    REFERENCES ROOM(BUILDINGNO, ROOMNO),
...
```

Test:

```
insert into building values (1, null, null);
insert into room values (1, 1, null);
insert into speaker (speakerid) values (1);
insert into conferencesession (sessionid,buildingno,roomno,speakerid) values (1, 1, 1, 1);
insert into conferencesession (sessionid,buildingno,roomno,speakerid) values (2, 1, 2, 1);
```

Last insert produces error `ORA-02291`.

Comment: This neither says nor explains what the contradiction in declarations is and it doesn't explain the options for solving the problem in the question.